# How to handle a function which should return an Observable only if validation succeeds?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I hope this is not too opinion-based. I'm thinking there may be a best-practice I don't know about, or a mechanism I don't know about, or I'd at least like a better understanding of the pros and cons of possible solutions.

Say I have these functions in an Angular service called ImportService that handles all the logic around importing:

```
  /** Only call this after calling validateImportFile and getting back true! */
  new(file: File): Observable<ImportResource> { 
    return this.apiService.importCreate(file);
  }

  validateImportFile(file: File): Boolean {
    //some validation logic
  }
```

If TypeScript were more like Java, I'd prefer to do something more like:

```
  new(file: File): Observable<ImportResource> throws ImportValidationError {
    if(this.validateImportFile(file)) {
      return this.apiService.importCreate(file);
    } else {
      throw new ImportValidationError("Your file is bad and you should feel bad");
    }
  }

  private validateImportFile(file: File): Boolean {
    //some validation logic
  }
```

So that callers could do something more like

```
try {
  importService.new(aFile).subscribe( importInfo => {
    //Display stuff about importInfo
  }, error => {
    //There was some kind of http error
  });
} catch (ImportValidationError e) {
    //There was something wrong with the file itself
}
```

The main benefits being

- new() will always validate and callers don't have to know/remember to call validate first
- the signature of new() clearly communicates to callers that they have to handle a validation failure
- callers of new() can easily distinguish between a validation failure case and some other failure case

but from what I've read throwing Errors in this way is a sort of anti-pattern in TypeScript right now because you can't put a "throws" declaration in the signature to alert callers to expect it, and the compiler won't expect callers to catch it, so all of those benefits are lost.

If I return an error observable instead, I don't think callers can know to expect a certain type of error specifically for validation failure.

Another option is to return a wrapper object that indicates whether there was an error and contains the observable only if successful, but this seems cluttered and roundabout enough that I have to wonder if there is a better way. Is there?

Comment: there's a catchError pipe operator and a second argument on the subscribe method, that display an error.

Comment: If you want try-catch, use it like this: `try { await observable.pipe(take(1)).to promise() } catch (error) {...} `

Comment: Describe how you want to provide a validation, if it's not enough and I'll try to help

Comment: Wait what. Try, Catch, await, Observable, Promise. Well I think no matter what's the issue, this can't be the solution. ( ͡ʘ ͜ʖ ͡ʘ)

Answer (score 0):

Functional reactive programming really works in a whole new different mind set, in FRP your code can be just as simple as following. Use the throwError from rxjs

```
const createNew=(file)=>
    this.validateImportFile(file)?
        throwError(new ImportValidationError("Your file is bad and you should feel bad")):
        this.apiService.importCreate(file);
```

usage

```
   createNew(yourfile).subscribe(()=>console.log('sucess'),err=>console.log(error))
```

Comment: Using the full TypeScript syntax to type the file parameter and the returned observable has the benefit of letting the caller know what type of parameter to send in (File) and what type of response to be emitted by the returned observable (ImportResource). Because of the TypeScript stuff, a caller can use the createNew() function without having to read its implementation. Is there any way to let the caller know that if the returned observable errors, the error may be of type "ImportValidationError"? If not, users of createNew() will have to read the implementation to know how to use it.

Comment: Looks like "no" for now https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2646, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219

Comment: You still can do that with the functional definitions, but not sure about error type. It is a pain to extend error class